# Timer tick event isn't raised on web browser navigating

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, webbrowser-control

I have a timer which is started on `WebBrowser` control navigating event

```
 void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
 {
    timer.Interval = 5;
    timer.Start();
 }
```

But when I navigate to some HTML files, the applications shows wait cursor for several seconds, nothing of the page is shown, and after the page was loaded, the timer tick event raises!

I tried to start the timer before navigating to the page, but it also has no effect.

Why the timer doesn't start and work as expected!?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the problem is with the webBrowser1_Navigating event and not with whatever code you have in the timer_Tick event?

Comment: @LukePark yes, I set a breakpoint in the Tick event, it is not fired until navigation ends.

Comment: I suspect you're blocking the `WebBrowser`'s thread with some kind of `WaitXXX` API or a nasty busy waiting loop like `while webBrowser.readyState != Complete);`